# Unable to install vaex in anaconda

Tags: anaconda3, vaex

I tried to import vaex in my company computer, but the proxy is blocking the pip install in the jupyter notebook. Is there a alternative to install due to proxy restriction?

I also tryied to install it in the command line, but I am getting this error:
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works for you, but using `conda` (rather than `pip` mentioned in the question) would require running this command:

```sh
conda install -c conda-forge vaex
```

Other installation options are described in the [docs](https://vaex.io/docs/installing.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use conda, it is best to use miniconda rather than anaconda. The use of anaconda might lead to dependency conflicts.